# Why jekyll is showing font in italics

Tags: jekyll

On my blog (https://ervikrant06.github.io/), I am not sure why but blog font is italic characters example : https://ervikrant06.github.io/kubernetes/Kuberenetes-prometheus-persistent-storage/

How can I change this to default non-italic characters?

I guess it has happened after adding the category functionality in my blog but not sure what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the following markup in your `_layouts/post.html`:
https://github.com/ervikrant06/ervikrant06.github.io/blob/3061c33012326ebd2b580b56f916453add3ab845/_layouts/post.html#L18-L19

```
<div class="date">
<div class="date">
```